# How to check for DOM .contains? in clojurescript?

Tags: dom, clojurescript, reagent, hiccup

In JS one does `document.some_element.contains(other_element)` to find whether an element is contained within another.

How to do this in Clojurescript/Hiccup/Reagent framework?

I have tried:

```
(js/contains some-element another-element)
(-> js/contains some-element another-element)
(.-contains some-element another-element)
(js/.contains some-element another-element)
```

Comment: What have you tried? CLJS compiles down to JS, so what works there should also work here.

Comment: Sure it does, but what's the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The proper syntax to call a method on an object is `(.contains a b)` which would be equal to `a.contains(b)`. The `js/` namespace is reserved for accessing the "global "scope and thus cannot be used with locals.

`(.contains a b)` can also be written as `(. a (contains b))`, which is actually what the `.contains` expands to after the compiler is done with it.

There is also `..` which allows chaining interop forms, so `(.. js/document -some-element (contains another-element))` would match `document.some_element.contains(another_element)`. Note that `js/document` here is accessing the global document.

`->` can also be used by requires repeating the `.`, eg `(-> js/document .-some-element (.contains another-element))`.

Comment: Thanks. What's the source?

Comment: @zengod - the JS Interop section of the CLJS Cheat Sheet is a good starting point: https://cljs.info/cheatsheet/ and also https://cljs.github.io/api/syntax/#dot